# Working with Name.com API (PHP)

Tags: php, api, class

I'm now working with Name.com API, They have documentary explanation of how to get details.

I've made everything right, But, I can't print the result.

I've done var_dump() to debug and here is the result:

```
object(stdClass)#4 (2) { 
    ["result"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { 
        ["code"]=> int(100) ["message"]=> string(18) "Command Successful" 
    } 
    ["domains"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (8) { 
        ["mynewdomain.mobi"]=> object(stdClass)#7 (5) { 
            ["avail"]=> bool(true) 
            ["tld"]=> string(4) "mobi" 
            ["price"]=> string(4) "8.99" 
            ["premium"]=> bool(false) 
            ["backorder"]=> bool(false) 
        } 
        ["mynewdomain.net"]=> object(stdClass)#8 (5) { 
            ["avail"]=> bool(false) 
            ["tld"]=> string(3) "net" 
            ["price"]=> string(5) "49.95"
            ["premium"]=> bool(false) 
            ["backorder"]=> bool(true) 
        } 
        ["mynewdomain.org"]=> object(stdClass)#9 (5) { 
            ["avail"]=> bool(true) 
            ["tld"]=> string(3) "org" 
            ["price"]=> string(4) "9.99" 
            ["premium"]=> bool(false) 
            ["backorder"]=> bool(false) 
        } 
        ["mynewdomain.info"]=> object(stdClass)#10 (5) { 
            ["avail"]=> bool(true) 
            ["tld"]=> string(4) "info" 
            ["price"]=> string(4) "3.99" 
            ["premium"]=> bool(false) 
            ["backorder"]=> bool(false) 
        } 
        ["mynewdomain.com"]=> object(stdClass)#11 (5) { 
            ["avail"]=> bool(false) 
            ["tld"]=> string(3) "com" 
            ["price"]=> string(5) "49.95" 
            ["premium"]=> bool(false) 
            ["backorder"]=> bool(true) 
        } 
        ["mynewdomain.biz"]=> object(stdClass)#12 (5) { 
            ["avail"]=> bool(false) 
            ["tld"]=> string(3) "biz" 
            ["price"]=> string(5) "29.95" 
            ["premium"]=> bool(false) 
            ["backorder"]=> bool(true) 
        } 
        ["mynewdomain.me"]=> object(stdClass)#13 (5) { 
            ["avail"]=> bool(false) 
            ["tld"]=> string(2) "me" 
            ["price"]=> string(5) "49.95" 
            ["premium"]=> bool(false) 
            ["backorder"]=> bool(true) 
        } 
        ["mynewdomain.tv"]=> object(stdClass)#14 (5) { 
            ["avail"]=> bool(false) 
            ["tld"]=> string(2) "tv" 
            ["price"]=> string(5) "49.95" 
            ["premium"]=> bool(false) 
            ["backorder"]=> bool(true) 
        }
    } 
}
```

and this is another short result for listing domains:

```
object(stdClass)#4 (2) { 
    ["result"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { 
        ["code"]=> int(100) 
        ["message"]=> string(18) "Command Successful" 
    } 
    ["domains"]=> array(0) { } 
}
```

I tried the following:

- `echo $response`
- `echo $response->domains`
- `echo $response['domains']`

But really, I can't get it to work..Could someone help me with that ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are getting a bunch of Objects back so you need to iterate through $response->domains. I'd push that to a new var for easier handling like:

```
$domains = &$response->domains;

foreach($domains as $key => $value) {
  echo $key.":\n";
  foreach($value as $a => $b) {
    if($b === true) $b = 'yes';
    if($b === false) $b = 'no';
    echo $a.": ".$b."\n";
  }
}
```

Note: $response->result ONLY contains the result of the command you sent the server. Check that to make sure you didnt error but dont expect your data to be in there.

Comment: I've tried this and get a white page, by debugging, I get: array(0) { }

Comment: Can you please do a serialize($response); - echo it and post it so I can bring the class into a test page and see whats going on?

Comment: Result has been came up but all domains are available:

`example.orgstdClass Object ( [avail] => [tld] => org [price] => 49.95 [premium] => [backorder] => 1 ) 
example.netstdClass Object ( [avail] => [tld] => net [price] => 49.95 [premium] => [backorder] => 1 ) 
example.infostdClass Object ( [avail] => [tld] => info [price] => 49.95 [premium] => [backorder] => 1 ) 
example.mobistdClass Object ( [avail] => [tld] => mobi [price] => 49.95 [premium] => [backorder] => 1 )`

Comment: OK so looks like it works then, I'll edit my answer to handle the objects in domain.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried your edited code and got all the objects but the same problem before, All domains are available, That's the result:

`google.com: avail: 
tld: com
price: 9.99
premium: 
backorder: `

Here it's also the serialize:`O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:6:"result";O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:4:"code";i:100;s:7:"message";s:18:"Command Successful";}s:7:"domains";O:8:"stdClass":8:{s:10:"google.net";O:8:"stdClass":5:{s:5:"avail";b:0;s:3:"tld";s:3:"net";s:5:"price";s:5:"49.95";s:7:"premium";b:0;s:9:"backorder";b:1;}}}`

Comment: Sorry, i see what you are saying about all avail, the problem is avail is a key and points to a boolean value. I made another edit to my answer to handle changing the boolean value to a YES or NO value. Should be easier to understand now - give it a shot!

Comment: Here it is the result for checking yahoo.com: `yahoo.me: yes: 1
tld: me
price: 7.99
no: 
no: `

Comment: Try again - i accidently set $a instead of $b - should work now... :P

Comment: :D I've checked for another domain and gets all available: `facebook.tv: avail: yes tld: tv price: 10.99 premium: no backorder: no `

Comment: So it works! name.com says its available - it can be backordered. However, its not on backorder so the backorder is set to no. Make sure you check your query against name.com's own front end. Hope this helps!

Comment: I've tried name.com for checking and it says all are registered, Would you like the full API ?

Comment: Trust me, at this point its not an issue with how we handle the data. Name.com is setting the field to TRUE in the available field. This is an issue with how they handle their API that you will need to take up with them.

Comment: And what about the second command that gets the domain list in the account, Result by debugging is: `object(stdClass)#4 (2) { ["result"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["code"]=> int(100) ["message"]=> string(18) "Command Successful" } ["domains"]=> array(0) { } }`

As you see the array is 0, But I've domains in the account.

Comment: Pardon me I've fixed the second command, Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one to get message:

```
echo $response->result->message;
```

To get domain list:

```
foreach ($response->domains as $domainName => $domainData)
{

    echo $domainName.": available-".$domainData->avail."; price - ".$domainData->price;

}
```

Comment: I get the message successfully but the list gives me white page.

Comment: @MohamedMagdy did you try my code below?
$domainData is the StdClass object

Comment: Tried it again with check_domain as I was trying it for list_domains, Message came successfully but all domains are available, It's not checking.

Comment: @MohamedMagdy in your second example domains is empty array. i posted code for first example where domains is stdClass object. may be you check it out with second data?

Comment: I've tried your code for this `$response = $api->check_domain('example');`

It worked successfully with the listing and price but all is availabe, Do you want to me to send you the full API with all classes inside ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that everything is in a `result` array first. Try this:

```
echo $response["result"]["domains"];
```

Comment: `domains` isn't a child element of `result`

Comment: Not worked:
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Hmmm, sorry, I didn't notice when the output was on one line when I answered.